# Copy rows from one table to another, ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql

Im trying to copy row from table to another using 2 coluom only as the tow table schema is not identical , 
am getting this error

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any tips  whats wrong with my statement ?

```
 Insert table1 ( screenname,list_id )
  Select screenname,list_id
 From table2 As T1
 Where Not Exists    (
                Select 1
                From table1 As T2
                Where 
               (T2.screenname = T1.screenname,T2.list_id = T1.list_id)
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change where condition from `(T2.screenname = T1.screenname,T2.list_id = T1.list_id)` to `(T2.screenname = T1.screenname AND T2.list_id = T1.list_id)`

(note AND keyword instead of comma)

Comment: correct :) looks like it was AND not comma , thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax?

See MySQL manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index in table1 on the columns screenname and list_id
Then use the following statement

> Insert ignore into table1 ( screenname,list_id )
>     Select screenname,list_id
>    From table2 As T1

Answer (score 0):

Also try this query -

```
INSERT INTO table1 (screenname, list_id)
  SELECT screenname, list_id FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1
      ON t1.screenname = t2.screenname AND t1.list_id = t2.list_id
  WHERE
    t1.screenname IS NULL AND t1.list_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple INSERT IGNORE

```
INSERT table1 (screenname, list_id) SELECT screenname, list_id FROM table2
```