# Insert rows from one table to another but only those rows that have no duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406036/insert-non-duplicate-rows-from-one-table-to-another-mysql), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805461/copy-two-columns-from-one-table-to-another-but-only-unique-values), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656012/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569642/how-to-insert-records-from-table-to-another-without-duplicate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739043/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-ignoring-duplicates) but my question is different.

I have a Table1:

```
id c a b rc bid
1 12 4 6 35 4 
2 12 4 6 67 7
3 12 4 6 88 8
4 23 4 7 49 3
5 23 5 8 59 8
```

Table2 also has the same columns but does not have `bid` column.

A row is considered a duplicate if it has the same values of columns `c`, `a` and `b`. So rows 1, 2 and 3 are considered duplicates because they have 12, 4 and 6.

I want to insert rows of `Table1` to `Table2`, but only those rows that are not duplicates. **Which means that rows 1, 2 and 3 won't get inserted to `Table2`**. Only rows 4 and 5 will get inserted because they have no duplicates.

So Table2 will look like this after the inserts:

```
id c a b rc
1 23 4 7 49
2 23 5 8 59
```

I know I can get which rows have no duplicates using this query:

```
select distinct c,a,b,count(*) from Table1 group by c,a,b having count(*) > 1
```

But am not able to figure out how to insert these to `Table2` because the insertion requires specific columns to be specified.

Tried something like this which obviously doesn't work:

```
insert into Table2 (c, a, b, rc) select distinct c,a,b,count(*) from Table1 group by c,a,b having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Also specify table2's data (after the insert).

Comment: *Table2 also has the same columns but does not have bid column.* - but on your INSERT you are using the `bid` column!?

Comment: Like you said `Table2` doesn't have `bid` column. Then why are you trying to insert like that `insert into Table2 (c, a, b, rc, bid)...`

Comment: Sorry. Corrected it. Table 2 shouldn't have the `bid` column

Comment: I've changed your query a bit, Would you please give it a try? `insert into Table2 (c, a, b, rc) select c,a,b,count(*) from Table1 group by c,a,b having count(*) = 1`

Comment: 'without duplicates', but searching for records where the combination appears more than once. Do you know how HAVING is working? Have you read the documentation? Is your SELECT working without the insert part? Have you test it?

Comment: @1000111 It worked. I can't believe it was that simple! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Pred I do go through the documentation and there is a lot I have to understand about SQL. Searching and asking on this forum is one of the ways I learn. From your answers and from the techniques I see y'all using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also not in in subselect

```
INSERT INTO Table2(c, a, b, rc, bid)
SELECT  c, a, b, rc, bid
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE (c,a,b) not in ( SELECT c,a,b 
      FROM Table1 t2
      GROUP BY c, a, b
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude duplicate rows:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(c, a, b, rc, bid)
SELECT
    c, a, b, rc, bid
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE
        t2.c = t1.c
        AND t2.a = t1.a
        AND t2.b = t1.b
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

The `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` will check if there are duplicates.

Comment: @sagi, yup. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Error: Unknown column 't2.c' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2 (c,a,b,rc)
select c,a,b,rc from table1 
where id in (select distinct id 
               from Table1 group by c,a,b having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the query gives this error `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Table1.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. You have already got so many correct answers. Here, I am giving the query based on the way you approached.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (c, a, b, rc) 
SELECT
    c,
    a,
    b,
    rc
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY c, a, b
HAVING  count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Oops. My mistake. This didn't give the right solution because in the inserted row, the fourth column ends up being the count value. The fourth column should be what is in the `rc` column.

Comment: That was silly. Corrected it. Actually I started to modify from your query. I didn't notice that. @Nav

Comment: Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'rc' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. It's ok the answer from scaisEdge works fine. Thank you, all the same.